# Regarding the if...else condition which is not working

Tags: java, return-value, return-type

The code that is shown below is working fine but only for one part, the if...else statement which must return -1 if the inputted month is less than 1 or more than 12 and the inputted year less than 1 or more than 9999

I have compile it many times, I have even tried rearranging the conditions like changing the less than to more than then putting the entire switch statement into the if statement. nothing seems to be working

```
public static int getDaysInMonth(int month, int year) {

        int maxDay = 31;
        int secMaxDay = 30;
        int specialDay = 29;
        int minDay = 28;

    if ((month < 1 || month > 12) && (year < 1 || year > 9999)) {
        return -1;

    } else {
        switch (month) {
            case 1:
            case 3:
            case 5:
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 10:
            case 12:
                return maxDay;

            case 2:
                if (isLeapYear(year)){
                    return specialDay;
                } else {
                    return minDay;
                }

            default:
                return secMaxDay;
        }
    }
}
```

The expected output for my above code is, when either the month or year or both have a value of less than 1 or more than the max value, it should return -1.

Comment: `&&` should be `||`.  Your question also contradicts itself.

Comment: *the month or year or both*: so you need an `or`, not an `and`.

Comment: Well you wrote the answer yourself, it should be or `||` beteeen the two conditions not and `&&`

Comment: that was a quick respond, thanks a lot the stack community. A newbie learning java, my bad.. thanks for helping me out once again

Comment: Out of topic - please be also aware that in Java Date/Calender API months are counted starting with 0. E.g. see in `java.util.Calendar` the constant `public final static int JANUARY = 0;`

Comment: noted Michal.. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment you are returning "-1" **only** if **both** conditions are true.

'`&&`' will only return `true` if both contitions are `true`.

So you should change

`if ((month < 1 || month > 12) && (year < 1 || year > 9999))`

with

`if ((month < 1 || month > 12) || (year < 1 || year > 9999))`

You can simplify it like:

```
if (month < 1 || month > 12 || year < 1 || year > 9999)
```

The problem was that (for instance) if `month < 1 || month > 12` is true but `year < 1 || year > 9999` is false, then `true && false` returns `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to return -1 only when both year AND month are bad ? or as soon as one is wrong if so, the && between the month and the year should be a || too